# Thread.dumpStack equivalent in Ruby

Tags: ruby, stack-trace

What is the equivalent of [the Java `dumpStack()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#dumpStack%28%29) in Ruby?

> `public static void dumpStack()`
>
> Prints a stack trace of the current thread to the standard error stream. This method is used only for debugging.
>
> See Also: [`Throwable.printStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Kernel#caller`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/caller) will give you the current call stack in array form. You can also set a starting and ending frame if you'd like only a portion of the stack.

```
def a(skip)
  caller(skip)
end
def b(skip)
  a(skip)
end
def c(skip)
  b(skip)
end
c(0)   #=> ["prog:2:in `a'", "prog:5:in `b'", "prog:8:in `c'", "prog:10:in `<main>'"]
c(1)   #=> ["prog:5:in `b'", "prog:8:in `c'", "prog:11:in `<main>'"]
c(2)   #=> ["prog:8:in `c'", "prog:12:in `<main>'"]
c(3)   #=> ["prog:13:in `<main>'"]
c(4)   #=> []
c(5)   #=> nil
```